# MySQL - Select date by different timezone

Tags: mysql

I've a database with a column of date in UTC timezone.

Now I would like to preform a select query by different time zone (PST).

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: the time zone of the server is static, so you can correct the user time by that timezone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could have a column specifying the time zone and than execute sql stmt like this

```
  " SELECT timeZone, timeStamp
    FROM tableName
    WHERE timeZone='UTC' "
```

could pass a variable in the where clause like this, this is how id do it in php

```
$TimeZone2Query = 'UTC';

" SELECT timeZone, timeStamp
  FROM tableName
  WHERE timeZone='$TimeZone2Query' "
```